# comparing attribute to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, attributes

I am creating an order form for work where you can add and remove rows with javascript. The issue I am having is after the most recent row has been removed I cannot add a new row.

I have a variable called `rid` which increments each time a row is added. I need to check the row to be deleted's id against the `rid`, if they are the same then it needs to lower the rid by one. I assume the issue is that the attribute and the variable are different types of string. The new rows are added using `$('#tr'+rid).after()`

```
$('div.remove').live("click", function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/r/, '');
            if(id === rid){
                rid = rid-1;
                alert(rid);
            }
            $('#tr'+id).remove();
});
```

Comment: You've said the issue you have is that you can't add a new row, but have only posted code that removes rows. Difficult to advise on fixing something that isn't shown!

Comment: Can you post your html? It seems there like there should be an easier way to do this. Also, you have a variable `rid` which is never defined in the code you posted. What is this and where does it come from?

Comment: try parsing the result of both the variables and then compare

Comment: I knew where the problem was and posting the add function would be irrelevant, the problem was down to id not being an integer and I didn't know how to make it one. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should cast `$(this).attr('id').replace(/r/, '')`  to an int value:

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/r/, ''), 10);
```

that should work

Comment: Don't forget to pass the radix as second parameter to `parseInt`, otherwise you will wonder about the result for strings starting with `0`. An easier way would be to use the unary `+`.

Comment: You're right Felix. I didn't mention it because i saw the row ids must be controlled by jonners, but good point